# Toggle list item elements greater than 3

Tags: jquery, css

I have a grouping of unordered list items and need to only show the first 3 `li` elements for each on load. When the user clicks the `+` sign, the remaining list items should toggle for only the list group clicked. I believe this could also be done with CSS only, but trying to get it functioning with jQuery.

This is my current implementation:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
    <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
    <ul>
      <li>link 1</li>
      <li>link 2</li>
      <li>link 3</li>
      <li>link 4</li>
      <li>link 5</li>
      <li>link 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
    <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
    <ul>
      <li>link 1</li>
      <li>link 2</li>
      <li>link 3</li>
      <li>link 4</li>
      <li>link 5</li>
      <li>link 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
    <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
    <ul>
      <li>link 1</li>
      <li>link 2</li>
      <li>link 3</li>
      <li>link 4</li>
      <li>link 5</li>
      <li>link 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul li').hide().filter(':lt(3)').show();
$('ul').append('<li>+</li>').find('li:last').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(':gt(2)').toggle();
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/zqy0qjgh/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your first line of jQuery to:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
  $('li:gt(2)', this).hide()
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/949f8ehb/)**

```js
$('ul').each(function() {
  $('li:gt(2)', this).hide()
});
$('ul').append('<li>+</li>').find('li:last').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(':gt(2)').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector worked within the entire element collection, so it only selects the first 3 `li` within the first `ul`

---

Instead, you can do it in two ways:

Using CSS [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) psudo-class selector, where [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) is used to avoid the last `+` in the list :

```
ul li:nth-child(n+4):not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
$('<li>+</li>').appendTo('ul').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('li:nth-child(n+3):not(:last-child)').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

ul li:nth-child(n+4):not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

With jQuery, using [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```
$('ul li:nth-child(n+4)').hide();
```

```js
$('ul li:nth-child(n+4)').hide();
$('<li>+</li>').appendTo('ul').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('li:nth-child(n+3):not(:last-child)').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With your own toggling code :

```js
$('ul li:nth-child(n+4)').hide();
$('ul').append('<li>+</li>').find('li:last').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(':gt(2)').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').each(function(){
  $(this).find('li').hide().filter(':lt(3)').show();
});
```

Try this.